# Decodificador para CAPTCHA de código aberto

Tags: java, código-aberto

Estou buscando alguma API para decodificação de CAPTCHA, uma que seja de livre utilização e com código fonte aberto.

Compreendo que se trata de um processo complexo que utiliza varreduras por OCR e técnimas avançadas de análise e processamento digital de imagens, mesmo assim acredito ser algo interessante de se estudar estes mecanismos por trás da decodificação.

Assim busquei algumas referências na web, foram elas:

**libautocaptcha**

Encontrei a [libautocaptcha](https://code.google.com/p/libautocaptcha/), porém sem sucesso na utilização. Após baixar o código fonte e bibliotecas necessárias ele apresenta erros por falta de classes.

**JDownloader**

Um aplicativo muito citado em foruns internacionais é o [JDonwloader](http://jdownloader.org), que internamente possui uma implementação (JAnticaptcha) que decodifica CAPTCHA dos principais sites de compartilhamento de arquivos.

**Tesseract OCR** [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)

Trata-se de um poderoso OCR que também é citado em foruns como uma boa opção para varrer a CAPTCHA e decoficá-la.

Diante disso tudo, alguém possui experiência com alguma outra API para decodificação ou numa dessas acima? Poderia oferecer algum exemplo funcional que resultou dessa experiência?

Answer (score 5):

Rotinas de quebra de captcha normalmente são **feitas para uma captcha específica**. Geralmente deve-se tratar a imagem antes de tentar ler ela com um OCR, tentando fazer com que as letras fiquem pretas em fundo branco. Um que recomendo é o tesseract, que você mesmo mencionou.

Não acho que existe, um algoritmo genérico para tal.

Comment: Que ótimo, um downvote sem explicação!

Comment: Dizem que há um único sistema que poderia decodificar vários captchas... é o sistema de reconhecimento de números das residências que o google utiliza no google maps... imagino que ao menos ele deva ser bom como dizem.

Comment: @FlávioGranato Nunca ouvi falar... você teria um endereço ou referência sobre este sistema?

Comment: é só um comentário, claro que já ouviu é o google maps que todos conhecem, ou não? Nele há um sistema interno para reconhecer os números por onde as câmeras dos carros do google passam. http://info.abril.com.br/noticias/internet/2014/04/algoritmo-do-google-desvenda-captchas-com-quase-100-de-acerto.shtml

Comment: @FlávioGranato Tranquilo! Eu conheço o Google Maps... o que eu queria era informações sobre o sistema de OCR deles: se é público, open-source, se existe alguma forma de utilizá-lo?

Comment: Só eles para te responder com precisão.

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, teoricamente, construir um software genérico que é treinado para resolver qualquer captcha e acredito que em alguns anos teremos isso disponível. Na minha empresa, [Infosimples](https://infosimples.com/), temos obtido resultados incríveis em problemas parecidos usando Deep Learning, tecnologia em que somos especialistas.

O artigo publicado pelo Google na ICLR14 a respeito de como eles automatizaram o reconhecimento de dígitos em números de casas pode ser encontrado neste link:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6082.pdf

A apresentação do artigo na ICLR14 pode ser vista neste vídeo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGPI_JvLoN0

Eles aplicaram a mesma solução no reCaptcha usando uma base com poucos milhões de exemplos e conseguiram resolver cerca de 100 mil novos captchas com 99,8% de taxa de acertos (melhor do que um ser humano na mesma atividade).

A essência da solução é treinar bases de dados (com milhões de exemplos) em uma rede neural muito profunda (com muitas camadas, convoluções e bilhões de conexões entre os neurônios).

Infelizmente, a tecnologia para obter resultados como os acima ainda é relativamente restrita, de difícil utilização e muito cara.