# Decodificador para CAPTCHA

Tags: java, java-ee, código-aberto

Preciso transformar um captcha em texto, sendo especifico, para realizar o download de NFE no site da **[Receita Federal](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8%3d)**, e para isso tenho lido a respeito do OCR porém, não parece ser 100% garantido, alguém já teve essa necessidade e/ou pode compartilhar o  caminho das pedras para conseguir traduzir esse captcha?

Comment: Muito provavelmente isso deveria estar sendo feito diretamente pela api da NFe mesmo. Se a nota envolve um fornecedor, o correto é importar do XML. Se é sua ou do seu cliente, você tem os dados. Se é de terceiros, a api permite ver se é válida. De resto, se não há envolvimento com nenhuma das partes, o captcha é justamente para evitar bots de escaneamento de dados de terceiros.

Comment: Olá Bacco, eu me enquadro na opção do bots, não sou nem o emissor e nem o destinatário, por isso não posso usar o serviço da SEFAZ, eu faço o frete e para evitar que minha equipe tenha que digitar todas as informações da NFE manualmente quero fazer o download, pois, o volume é enorme.

Comment: Opa, olha ai nas questões ativas: [decodificador-para-captcha-de-codigo-aberto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4422/decodificador-para-captcha-de-codigo-aberto)

Comment: Uma alternativa seria importar o captcha na sua aplicação então, aí sua equipe digitaria só o captcha. Agora, creio que o cliente te mandaria o XML numa boa, não?

Comment: Muitos clientes nem sabe o que é xml, porém, alguns já mandam, porém são a minoria.. Obrigado Bacco

Answer (score 9):

Tenho certeza que muitas repostas boas surgirão, mas vou deixar aqui meu 1 centavo sobre a questão.

Em minhas pesquisas vi muito sobre o **[Tesseract da Google](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)** que é um dos códigos OCR mais eficientes que existe. Mas não cheguei a desenvolver nada, foi apenas pesquisa.

Fiz sim alguns testes, mas sem uma customização para o fim específico, que é a resolução do captcha da Receita, você terá muitos erros para pouquíssimos acertos.

A versão mais recente do `Tesseract` é o **3.02.02**, até o momento.
Até a versão 2.32, se não me engano, era possível fazer um wrapper da biblioteca do Tesseract que é escrita em C++ para C e assim usar com mais facilidade por outras linguagens. Acho que hoje, como o **[TesseractEngineWrapper](https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/wiki/TesseractEngineWrapper)** para .Net, é mais fácil tentar achar algo que já faça o Wrapper dela para Java, que é o seu caso.

E cheguei a ver também serviços on-line que oferecem para fazer o decaptcha para você, como o **[captchabot.com](http://captchabot.com/)** e o **[deathbycaptcha.com](http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/)**. Mas também não os testei.

Ah uma certa discussão sobre isso ser legal ou não.

Tem um rapaz que implementou algo com esses serviços, ele envia o captcha para a API de um desses sites, o site faz o decaptcha para ele e retorna o texto, e então ele efetua o acesso e trabalha o HTML, **[veja aqui](http://www.fsist.com.br/)**.

O blog dele é: **http://fsist.blogspot.com.br**. Bom, mas é só para que você conheça o que já tem sido feito.

Mas gostaria de incentivá-lo a pesquisar por download da NFe, o próprio XML, diretamente pelo WebService da Receita Federal, só precisa ter o certificado.

Comment: Obrigado Tiago, o download a partir do WS da Receita tem uma restrição de que somente posso realizar o download se for o destinatário da NF, o que eu não sou. Temos um volume de mais de 1.000 onde um equipe fica digitando os dados se eu conseguir realizar o download não precisaremos mais de tanto trabalho... Obrigado. Fernando

Comment: Muito interessante essa API do google, vou avaliar, muito obrigado.

Comment: Acho que a solução mais adequada para você, no momento, é como a que o @Bacco deu. Ou seja, sua equipe informar o captcha e então você trabalhar o HTML. Sabe-se lá quanto tempo você vai investir em buscar uma solução de captcha, a não ser que você resolva investir dinheiro nisso e pagar um serviço ou comprar algo pronto. Porque é como falei em minha resposta, sem uma adequação você não vai conseguir efetuar o processo de OCR na imagem facilmente.