# Automatizar processo - Robô?

Tags: php

Tem uma página em php em que tenho que efetuar várias consultas. Essa página não sou eu que administro e não tenho nenhuma informação quanto a seu código-fonte.

O que é feito nessa página: É digitado um valor em um input e aguardado retorno com as informações de que preciso. (um POST normal, certo?)

O que preciso: Como são várias consultas, queria algo que automatizasse este processo. Um tipo de um robô que efetuasse essas consultas e armazenasse o resultado em qualquer arquivo externo (txt, csv). Gostaria que esse robô pegasse o valor que tem que ser digitado neste campo em uma lista de dados que eu tenho e vá apagando ou só marcando como "feito" conforme vai consultando para este valor.

Pesquisando achei algo sobre CURL. Funcionaria neste caso?
Alguém tem alguma idéia de como fazer algo assim?

Comment: E o que você já fez? Este site não é um fórum, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas objetivas. A sua pergunta está bastante ampla porque você basicamente está pedindo pra alguém fazer pra você. Tem inúmeros aspectos relacionados, não só a execução automatizada do post (veja esta pergunta de exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45142/73) como também a eventual necessidade de "burlar" um CAPTCHA (veja esta outra pergunta de exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11757/73).

Comment: Sugiro [edit] a pergunta pra torná-la mais específica em um problema que você encontrar no seu processo de desenvolvimento (por exemplo: como obter a resposta a um POST efetuado para um endereço qualquer). E também fazer o [tour] e ler a [help].

Comment: Assim, sem querer ser grosso mas eu não pedi pra fazer um script. Apresentei o processo que tenho de fazer para chegar ao objetivo que é o resultado do post com as informações. Não é um site de perguntas? Pois então, estou perguntando se alguém tem idéia de como posso fazer isso. Tem várias formas de resolver isso? Também tem diversas formas de responder alguém que está com problemas em código-fonte, por exemplo. Mas vamos lá, qual a sua sugestão? Criar uma macro? Eu não conhecia macro, agora vou pesquisar sobre isso. Não era mais fácil ter falado só: pesquise sobre macro?

Comment: Não tem a necessidade de burlar o CAPTCHA. Obrigado pelo link no primeiro comentário.

Comment: Não se preocupe, não foi grosso. :) Sim, esse é um site de perguntas *objetivas*, isto é, passíveis de receberem uma resposta igualmente objetiva. O Yahoo Respostas também é um site de perguntas e respostas, mas bem diferente deste e mais próximo de um fórum. Acho que as pessoas vão ter muitas ideias de como fazer o que você quer, mas como argumentei é um problema muito amplo pra ser respondido no formato que este site propõe (ao menos em uma só pergunta). Aliás, o CAPTCHA foi só um exemplo. Há outros aspectos relevantes que ainda estão no amplo escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Buscarei outros meios para conseguir uma solução.

Comment: Hey, aqui são estritamente chatos com isso, é pra manter o nível da comunidade. Fóruns não estão sendo muito bem quistos, por serem cheios de perguntas bobas sem nexo que você não entende. Acho que essa pergunta não é ampla, ela tem um foco.

Comment: O que o rapaz disso acima sobre CAPTCHAS foi que se houver perguntas no formulário (Quanto é 1+2 + 4/5?, ou imagens para digitar (como as placas que o CAPTCHA usa), ou botões para clicar.. Enfim, todas essas coisas são para impedir que robôs funcionem da forma que voce quer.. se houver esse tipo se “segurança” vai ser difícil ou quase impossível fazer seu robo funcionar, pois eles não possuem inteligência artificial suficiente para “ver” a imagem, ou interpretar a equação.. Existem formas? Sim, mas são complexas e estão engatinhando ainda...

Comment: CASO não tenha esse tipo de segurança a opção mais viável (que eu conheça) na linguagem PHP é o cURL, voce vai usa-lo para entrar no site e preencher os inputs e enviar.. e assim voce vai criar seu robo.. caso tenha duvidas me chame, eu respondo.

Comment: Obrigado. No primeiro acesso tem um login mas que é sem segurança nenhuma (captcha). Depois disso é só um input e apertar o botão de consultar (Também sem segurança). Com esse CURL é possível passar por essas barreiras e copiar as informações que vem do POST?

Comment: Desculpe a demora na resposta, se você não marcar o usuario ( @USERNAME) ele não é notificado. Sim, veja só essas explicações, http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post, http://blog.thiagobelem.net/login-automatico-em-php-usando-curl/

Comment: Obrigado @user3163662. Não conhecia cURL até então. Estou movendo essa discussão para outra pergunta, já que essa deixaram como pendente. Se vc puder dar uma olhada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76674/php-curl-sess%C3%A3o-terminada