# PHP - CURL Sessão terminada?

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando criar um robo para automatizar um processo, conforme post aqui: [Automatizar processo - Robô?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76643/automatizar-processo-robo)

Dada as sugestões, estou seguindo utilizando cURL. O que esta acontecendo é o seguinte: Ele consegue fazer o login, vai para a segunda página onde tem o form que eu quero que seja feito o POST mas ele não me retorna nada. Minha dúvida é se eu tenho que utilizar algum comando que guarde a sessão do login. Pois pelo que estou vendo ele está retornando um link que apresenta Usuario e senha invalido ou Sessão invalido no segundo POST. Segue meu código:

```
    // Inicia o cURL
   $ch = curl_init();

// Define a URL original (do formulário de login)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.com/consulta/index.php');

// Habilita o protocolo POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Define os parâmetros que serão enviados
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'usuario=teste&senha=teste');
// Imita o comportamento patrão dos navegadores: manipular cookies
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
// Define o tipo de transferência (Padrão: 1)
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Executa a requisição
$store = curl_exec ($ch);

// Define uma nova URL para ser chamada (após o login)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.com/consulta/forms.php');
// Habilita o protocolo POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Define os parâmetros que serão enviados
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'campoNome=Joao');

// Executa a segunda requisição
$content = curl_exec ($ch);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' . 
                curl_error($ch);

// Encerra o cURL
curl_close ($ch);
```

Se eu coloco um echo do $content sai a página do form, mas sem nada de informação ou campos digitados..

Comment: Eu precisaria rodar o script para te dar uma resposta exata, conhece o pastebin? é um repositório onde voce pode determinar o tempo máximo que o arquivo vai ficar disponivel, se possivel crie um com seu código completo para eu rodar e apontar suas falhas..

Comment: @user3163662 O site e o usuário não são meus. Eu não poderia passar assim, mas entendo que vc só conseguiria ver com o completo. Mas a princípio, a requisição, a estrutura está certa?

Comment: Me parece que os cookies não estao indo para a segunda página em que você quer obter os resultados, então você precisa ativar eles. Fiz uma pesquisa (recomendo que faça sempre pesquisas em ingles, pois é mais facil de encontrar perguntas respondidas) onde o usuário queria o mesmo que você, ve se lhe serve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241344/grabbing-data-from-a-website-with-curl-after-logging-in

Answer (score 3):

Você não reutiliza os cookies e por isso não tem a resposta correta.
Uma dica é criar métodos para cada tipo de requisição, onde esses irão reutilizar os cookies:

```
function getRequest($url, $myCookieFile) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $myCookieFile,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $myCookieFile
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}

function postRequest($url, $data, $myCookieFile) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $myCookieFile,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $myCookieFile
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

Com os métodos acima implementados você pode manter a persistência da sessão entre as páginas.
Um exemplo de utilização seria o seguinte:

```
// Primeira requisição para postar data e ter minha sessão
postRequest('http://site.com/sessao-para-pegar-os-cookies', 'usuario=teste&senha=teste', 'cookies.txt');

// Segunda requisição com os cookies da primeira requisição
$resposta = getRequest('http://site.com/pagina-para-usuarios-autenticados', 'cookies.txt');
```