# Macro para acessar site com login

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, web-scraping

Executo uma rotina diariamente de acessar o site do Serasa e fazer a consulta de CNPJ. Preciso desenvolver uma macro para acessar esse site do Serasa, efetuar o login e depois a consulta, e em seguida jogar as informações no Excel.  Detalhe: Já consegui desenvolver a macro pra acessar o site, mas na hora da consulta de CNPJ, da erro de Script e não deixa copiar as informações. Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível que a macro execute todas essas atividades?

```
Sub FazerLoginSite()
    Dim IE As Object Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With IE 
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("serasaexperian.com.br/")
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4:
            DoEvents:
        Wend
        .Document.getElementById("inputLogin").Focus
        .Document.getElementById("inputLogin").Value = "Meu Login"
        .Document.getElementById("senha").Focus
        .Document.getElementById("senha").Value = "Minha Senha"
        .Document.All("btnOk").Click
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4:
            DoEvents:
        Wend 
        Debug.Print .LocationURL
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Olá. Estou sem tempo pra testar e tentar bolar uma resposta. Mas dá uma olhada [nessa thread do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173320/submit-form-and-fetch-data-from-website-vba) com outra forma de solução (sem usar o navegador). Pode ser de alguma ajuda. :)

Comment: Valeu Luiz... Vou testar e te falo.. Abs

Comment: Luiz, dei uma olhada nesse link, mas não compreendi muito bem. Se consegui me ajudar mais tarde com isso, fico grato. Abs

Comment: Eu utilizaria o imacros (http://imacros.net) no firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/). Você GRAVA as ações e depois executa.

Comment: Márcio, o artigo que o @luiz-vieira apontou é muito interessante pq a pessoa da pergunta esta com um problema relativamente parecido com a sua e a pessoa que respondeu mostrou que é muito mais fácil usar     MSXML2.XMLHTTP para enviar um request pra página e pegar o response num MSHTML.HTMLDocument e ler os dados de dentro desse MSHTML.

Comment: @Márcio é possivel fazer tudo isso sim, porém precisamos que você forneça uma imagem da planilha ou o código completo que você conseguiu criar...Como que vocÊ indica quais CNPJs devem ser acessados? Você ja coloca toda a lista de CNPJ em uma sheet ou você quer colocar manualmente um a um?

Comment: Paulo Roberto, boa tarde! Na verdade não criei a planilha ainda, mas a ideia é criar uma planilha com cerca de 40 CNPJ's, e criar um hiperlink em cada um deles... Assim que clicar ele já acessa o site, pesquisa o CNPJ e retorna as informações no Excel. Ou se possível, clicar num botão e pesquisar vários CNPJ's de uma vez só. O código que consegui elaborar está postado acima. Fico muito grato se conseguir me ajudar. Obrigado! Márcio

Comment: Oi Márcio. Esse serviço é pago, não é? Vc não tem acesso ao *web service* deles (que é citado nesta página: http://www.serasaexperian.com.br/consultas/validade-informacoes-pessoa-juridica/pme-meios-de-acesso.html)?

Comment: Isso é bem complicado, ja tentei buscar também, mas existia um bloqueio por Captcha(aquelas imagens de segurança) que impedia a busca de prosseguir.
É por isso que eles cobram por essa busca e bloqueiam o acesso.
Vai ser difícil, mas se conseguir parabéns!

Comment: O cara "criou" o código exatamente igual a este daqui http://excelevba.com.br/fazer-login-em-um-site-usando-vba/ e depois não conseguiu criar mais nada?? Acho que falta humildade para algumas pessoas.

Answer (score 8):

Como eu já havia comentado anteriormente, dá pra fazer usando as bibliotecas *Microsoft HTML Object* e *Microsoft XML, v6.0*. Elas precisam ser referenciadas dentro do VBA (na janela de código, acesse o menu `Ferramentas -> Referências` e marque essas bibliotecas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois, você precisa analisar o código HTML/Javascript da página com o formulário de interesse para descobrir:

1. Quais são os campos e valores necessários para o envio da requisição
2. Qual é o método de requisição (POST ou GET, por exemplo)
3. Qual é o endereço da `action` do formulário (se for vazio, é o próprio endereço da página com o formulário)

Então, monte um código mais ou menos como esse:

```
Sub GenMegaSenaNumbers()
On Error Resume Next

    Dim oHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim oDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim oText As HTMLParaElement
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sParameters As String

    ' Defina aqui a URL da página de requisição do formulário
    sURL = "https://www.random.org/quick-pick/index.php"
    ' Defina aqui os parâmetros para a consulta
    ' (usando EXATAMENTE os mesmos nomes dos campos no formulário)
    sParameters = "tickets=1&lottery=6x60.0x0"

    ' Faz a consulta dos dados
    Cells(1, 1) = "Aguarde. Fazendo a consulta pelos números do jogo..."

    Set oHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    oHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    oHttp.Open "GET", sURL & "?" & sParameters, False
    oHttp.send

    ' Se o método de acesso for POST ao invés de GET, use assim:
    'oHttp.Open "POST", sURL, False
    'oHttp.send sParameters

    ' Checa se o carregamento foi efetuado corretamente
    If oHttp.Status <> 200 Then
        Cells(1, 1) = "Oops! Não foi possível obter a resposta! Erro: (" & Str(oHttp.Status) & " )" & oHttp.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Obtem a resposta
    Set oDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    oDoc.body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText

    ' E lê o dado do elemento desejado
    Set oText = oDoc.getElementsByClassName("data").Item(0)
    Cells(1, 1) = "Sugestão de jogo para a Mega-Sena: " & oText.innerText

End Sub

Sub Botão1_Click()

    GenMegaSenaNumbers

End Sub
```

Esse exemplo tem uma macro (a sub `Botão1_Click`) anexada a um botão que executa a sub `GenMegaSenaNumbers`, que de fato é a responsável por fazer a requisição e obter a resposta. Nesse exemplo eu consulto a geração de números aleatórios para um jogo de Mega-Sena, [serviço gratuito e disponível pelo site Random.org](https://www.random.org/quick-pick/). O formulário nessa página tem vários campos (inclusive um oculto que é dinamicamente montado por Javascript), mas eu usei [a ferramenta de desenvolvedor do Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), na aba *Network*, para identificar quais parâmetros ele enviava na requisição (muito mais fácil! e deu pra perceber que nem todos os campos eram necessários).

Note que há diferença na forma de passar os parâmetros no VBA se o método é POST ou GET (no caso do exemplo, era GET). Note também o parâmetro `False` na chamada de `oHttp.Open` (terceiro parâmetro, que não existe na resposta do SOEN original que [eu mencionei nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45142/macro-para-acessar-site-com-login#comment90497_45142)). Ele indica que a chamada *não é* assíncrona, e assim não é necessário fazer o laço com o `DoEvents` para esperar o resultado (o próprio Excel gerencia isso pra você, fazendo a chamada ser síncrona).

Eis o screenshot do resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> OBSERVAÇÃO IMPORTANTE: Naturalmente esse método **não funciona**
>   com formulários que requerem validação por CAPTCHA. Afinal, é
>   justamente essa a intenção de um (bom) CAPTCHA: impedir que automatismos
>   sejam executados na página. Para entender (se precisar), sugiro ler
>   mais a respeito na [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) e aqui mesmo no SOPT([sugestão de
>   leitura 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11757/decodificador-para-captcha) e [sugestão de leitura 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4422/decodificador-para-captcha-de-c%C3%B3digo-aberto)). Independentemente disso, a
>   solução ideal (e provavelmente, legal) é usar um Web Service sempre que disponível.
>   O consumo de Web Services nas versões mais novas do Excel é [bastante simples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819156%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: OK Luiz Vieira, Vou tentar tudo isso.. Depois posto aqui o resultado. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Abs, Márcio

Comment: Deu certo @Márcio ?