# Problema com integração VBA e Internet Explorer

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Estou tentando utilizar VBA para coletar dados diretamente da internet. Vi vários exemplos da utilização do Objeto InternetExplorer, como abaixo:

```
Dim IE as Object
Set IE  = New InternetExplorer

IE.navigate "http://www.minhapagina.com.br"

html = IE.Document
```

Assim, poderia manipular o Objeto 'html' e obter os dados que necessito, no entanto, o objeto 'Document' vem sempre vazio. Como proceder?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45142/macro-para-acessar-site-com-login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica se ajuda:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Set IE  = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True 'para verificar se abre o browser
IE.navigate "http://www.minhapagina.com.br"

'possivelmente esta é a parte que te falta
Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
```

Um bom exemplo: 
[Get Data from Website that Requires a Login](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/03/08/get-data-from-website-that-requires-a-login/)