# Consultar CPF na Receita Federal

Tags: php, jquery

Gostaria de alguma forma consultar o nome da pessoa através do CPF no site da receita.
Existem aplicativos no android que basta colocar o CPF e ele trás o nome e a situação cadastral.
Porém no site tem um captcha.

Alguém já fez algo parecido ?

em php, jquery

Comment: [Esses aplicativos devem integrar com serviços pagos, tipo este](http://www.keyconsultasweb.com.br/consultas-via-webservice).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não fiz mas tenho um amigo q já fez isso, o q ele faz e baixar o conteúdo da página para um stream string tratar a  lógica preenchendo os campos. Já o CAPTCHA foi contornado com a técnica de pegar o áudio e  usar um recurso de descobrir a letra q infelizmente não posso dizer como por ética, mas o caminho e esse

Comment: Se o problema é o CAPTCHA em si, já há [algumas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4422/decodificador-para-captcha-de-c%C3%B3digo-aberto) perguntas [por aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11757/decodificador-para-captcha) que tratam do mesmo assunto.

Comment: Há uma solução através de API
https://gist.github.com/Pompeu/ce58d61cde1e51a1da164404d667d458

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu fiquei na dúvida sobre responder essa pergunta, passar conhecimento nunca é de mais, quem lê decide se irá implementar e sobre as eventuais ilegalidades, só vou abordar como tecnicamente seria possível passar por sistemas assim.

Em primeiro lugar você realmente vai precisar construir um robô que automatize os métodos para passar pelo Captcha, hoje em dia a grande maioria das opções são imagem e áudio.

**Imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faça análise visual e tente encontrar quais são os padrões existentes, só de observar (dar refresh várias vezes no captcha) dá pra concluir que os ruídos  parecem ser um problema, mas o que você poderia fazer para melhorar isso ?
infelizmente não espere encontrar nada pronto você terá que desenvolver os algoritmos, de ante mão garanta que a imagem esteja realmente em preto e branco, procure por pixels pretos conectados e remova pixels conectados menores que um tamanho X, isso vai limpar todos os pontinhos existentes na imagem, o próximo passo agora seria remover as linhas que cortam e as vezes cruzam as letras da imagem, uma solução é procurar na matriz da imagem quais pixels pretos estão em reta e limpe os pixels que estejam em trajetória reta maior que valor X definido por você. Pois bem se você fez isso com sucesso sua imagem vai estar limpa e você poderá submeter a mesma para um [OCR](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconhecimento_%C3%B3tico_de_caracteres), você vai precisar conhecer um pouco sobre cálculos de matrizes e sobre processamento de sinais em imagens.

**Audio**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse Audio diz **N H J K H j**

Não tem muita alternativa você vai precisar analisar e tratar o áudio também, primeiro passo, tem um monte de ruído e chiado quando você escuta o áudio, o primeiro problema é um forte ruído que é mais perceptível entre cada letra falada, isso é uma tentativa de confundir algoritmos que tente segmentar (recortar) cada letra, ao fazer uma análise de [fourier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Fourier) nos primeiros 2048 frames posso dizer em quais frequencias e qual é a média de amplitude que gera esse ruído estranho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tá ai, é um ruído realmente, frequências oscilando em todo o espectro e com pico linear mais ou menos em 78 de magnitude, mas que em média as frequências oscilam abaixo do 10 de magnitude .

OK mas e se você fizer outra análise de fourier no pedaço da primeira letra **N**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que você pode fazer aqui é utilizar um filtro passa alta e deixar passar só frequências acima de 50Hz (50hz é o mínimo que a voz humana emite), desta maneira você de cara já anula qualquer ruído acontecendo nas frequências baixas, entre 120 e 600 hertz você nota como para a letra N as frequências se concentram mais, se você fizer uma análise em todas as letras de áudio deste captcha não vai encontrar frequências superiores que 1000hz, podemos então construir um equalizador que atenue ou elimine ruídos acontecendo acima desta faixa, isso vai te dar um áudio mais limpo, até então você só tratou o áudio, você vai precisar extrair e tratar o áudio para cada letra na mão tipo(A.wav, B.wav), feito isso automatize o processo, faça um algoritmo que segmente o áudio automaticamente recortando onde cada letra começa e termina, trate da mesma forma que foi feito com os arquivos de cada letra e calcule a [correlação cruzada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o_cruzada), o resultado desta correlação te dirá qual é a letra.

Resumindo não existe caminho fácil, você vai ter um trabalho grande e ainda corre o risco que o site mude o sistema (algoritmo) do captcha.

Answer (score 2):

Recentemente fiz isso em C#, porém não "passei por cima" do CAPTCHA, eu trouxe a imagem e pedi pro usuário digitar, assim como é no web site, porém dentro da minha aplicação.

Vi um dia desses uma solução que "quebrava" o CAPTCHA, porém acredito ser um tanto ilegal e portanto nem vou indicar (também era em C#). O cara tinha feito engenharia reversa de um APK do Android e obtido a chave da aplicação, usada nos requests para fazer a busca.

Acredito que já existam soluções prontas na internet, mas caso queira implementar a sua, é como o @CiganoMorrisonMendez falou. Você vai fazer o chamado "web scrapping", lendo informações de uma página web e enviando requisições diretamente para o servidor deles, simulando a ação no browser.

Para isso, provavelmente irá utilizar a função CURL. Aconselho também usar o Fiddler para inspecionar as requisições e entender o fluxo de tráfego das informações.

Abraço.

Comment: Olá Joel, realmente existem essas duas formas, porém o captcha é um pouco incomodo para o usuario da empresa q estou prestando servico. 
Nao sei quanto a legalidade, mas estou investindo na engenharia reversa do APK android. 
Assim q concluir posto aqui